# capture input text from url in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using django rest framework to take two string from URL and output as a json response.
below is the code I have tried and the response I got.
Input URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict/?solute=CC(C)(C)Br&solvent=CC(C)(C)O`. here inputs are `CC(C)(C)Br` and `CC(C)(C)O` and I was expecting the json response contains both the inputs but I got null as output

This is my `urls.py` file

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def result(request):
    response = {}
    solute = request.POST.get('solute')
    solvent = request.POST.get('solvent')
    results = [solute,solvent]
    return Response({'result':results}, status=200)
```

I got null as output json response
[image]

Comment: You use `GET` request and `GET` parameters. And you try to get them with `request.POST`. Maybe `request.GET` would be a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the data as [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), so you access this with [**`request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET):

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def result(request):
    response = {}
    solute = request.GET.get('solute')
    solvent = request.GET.get('solvent')
    results = [solute,solvent]
    return Response({'result':results}, status=200)
```